# How to automate Eclipse using QTP 10

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, qtp

This is first time I was thinking about this scenario. I have few scripts in Selenium webdriver and few script in QTP.

Using Webdriver, I have automated web based HTML5 Application via Eclipse Juno, and using QTP I have automated SAP Purchase request placing order.

Now both become depended module for me, from SAP data's are flowing to web base application.

And I'm planning to automate Eclipse via QTP so that it will execute selenium script.

Can someone provide me how to proceed with situation and give me some strategy to proceed?

Thanks in advance
Raj R

Answer (score 1):

Since the Eclipse UI is written in Java you should be able to automate Eclipse using QTP's Java addin.

Answer (score 0):

If it is reasonable possible, I wouldn't record actions on Eclipse from QTP. Are you aware that eclipse has a [rich set of runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)? See if you can create an eclipse .ini file that starts the desired Selenium test. When it works as desired, you can start this file with the `SystemUtil.Run` statement in QTP.